# how to check if a string is of the form dd-mm-yy

Tags: java, string

I'm trying to test on a String, if it is of the form dd-mm-yyyy. Any help please?

Sorry, i'm just a beginner.

Comment: Have you learned about regular expressions yet?  They are a good way to check for matches in formatting.

Comment: There are two solutions - one that checks the format to be valid, and the other one checks that not only the format, but also the date is also valid. The first can be done with a simple regex; the second can be done with a date formatter.

Comment: Please explain what test you're trying to run, post minimal examples. Help us help you!

Comment: Are you trying to validate that a String is s date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(myString.matches("\\d{2}-\\d{2}-\\d{4}")){
    //Do something
}
```

The double-backslashes are used as one is used for the compiler to interpret the second literally, and the literal one as part of the string is used to make the `\d` escape sequence for a digit.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of just checking `dd-mm-yyyy`, which would allow inputs like `99-99-9999`, you could just use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to actually parse and check if it's a valid date:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
formatter.parse("99-99-9999");
formatter.parse("18-07-2013");
```

If the date is invalid it'll throw a [ParseException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/ParseException.html), which you can then catch and handle the error appropriately.

***Edit:***

As Bohemian pointed out, this doesn't actually throw an exception on the `99-99-9999` input. Instead, it kind of "rolls over" to interpret the bad date as a legal date. I think they might have done this on purpose to make date arithmetic easier. For example, `10-13-2000` becomes `10-1-2001` after parsing (there is no 13th month, so it becomes the 1st month of the next year instead). If you want it to throw an exception instead, you need to tell it to not be lenient:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
formatter.setLenient(false); // <== Added this line
formatter.parse("99-99-9999");
formatter.parse("18-07-2013");
```

Comment: -1 It may surprise you, but this code throws no exceptions when executed. See if you can figure out why. If you do, let me know and I'll undo the downvote. It's worth it to figure it out by yourself, because then you won't forget it

Comment: @Bohemian - Wow, I really should have tested that. (Unfortunately I don't have Scala installed on this machine, and that's what I typically use as my Java REPL.) Thanks for correcting me. I've edited my answer.

Comment: You haven't fixed it. There us a way to make it thruw an exception for invalid dates instead if rolling over. Keep hunting!

Comment: @Bohemian - Updated again, and thanks again! This is why I like posting on StackOverflow—I learn unexpected things! I've also installed Groovy so I can test the code I post more easily.

Answer (score 3):

```
String test = "13-04-1999";

try {
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
  sdf.setLenient(false);
  sdf.parse(test);
} catch(ParseException ex) {
  //string is not valid Date in your format  
}
```

Comment: -1 This will not throw any exceptions.

Comment: forgot about the normalization, thx

Comment: Normalisation? No that is not it. There is a way to make it throw exceptions - see other answer

Comment: Calendar in lenient mode returns fields normalized, if theres a missmatch.